# Canvas, animate a shape along square path using sine wave

Tags: javascript, animation, math, canvas, coffeescript

I'm trying to make a simple shape animate along a square path based on a set 'radius'. Atm I'm using a sine wave to set the position over time, so its basically animating along a circular path.
Is there a way using maths to alter the sine wave to make the animation square. I know there are other ways to do this, but I'd be interested to learn the math behind it.

I have an example fiddle:

```
t = new Date().getTime()

r = 25

x = (r * Math.cos t * 0.005) 
y = (r * Math.sin t * 0.005)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z5hrM/1/

Answer (score 1):

We can do better than just circle or square!  The equations for x and y can be generalized with an exponent D:

```
 x = (r^D * cos(theta))^(1/D) and y = (r^D * sin(theta))^(1/D)
```

When D = 1 you have the familiar equations that give a circle.  When D = 0.5 you get a diamond, when D < 0.5 you get pointed stars.  When D > 1 you get increasingly blocky shapes, and as D -> infinity you get a square.
Give it a try with this snippet; you can type new values of D as the animation proceeds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>animation problem</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function demo(){
        var w = 400;
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width = w;
        ctx.canvas.height = w;
        var r = w/4;
        var theta = 0;

        setInterval(function(){
            ctx.canvas.width += 0;    //  clear the canvas
            ctx.translate(w/2, w/2);  //  center it on (0,0)
            var D = +document.getElementById("exponent").value;

            var xSign = Math.cos(theta) < 0 ? -1 : 1;  // Handle all quadrants this way
            var ySign = Math.sin(theta) < 0 ? -1 : 1;
            var x = xSign*Math.pow( Math.pow(r, D)*Math.abs(Math.cos(theta)), 1/D );
            var y = ySign*Math.pow( Math.pow(r, D)*Math.abs(Math.sin(theta)), 1/D );
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.arc( x, y, 20, 0, 6.2832, false );
            ctx.fill();

            theta += Math.PI/100;
        }, 20);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload='demo()'>
    <input id='exponent' type=text value='1'\>
    <br />
    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/7U75G/)***

It actually isn't going to take much modification. Considering that the cosine represents the x coordinate, and the sin represents the y coordinate, it should be obvious that to make a square path one of these values must be set to a whole value instead of a partial value.

As a result, Math.cos t and Math.sin t will need to be regulated with a variable and a condition

```
xcos = Math.cos t * 0.005
ysin = Math.sin t * 0.005

if Math.abs(xcos) > Math.abs(ysin)
 xcos = Math.round(xcos)                                       
else
 ysin = Math.round(ysin)     

x = @cx + (radius * xcos)
y = @cy + (radius * ysin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable r should be a vector of two position (x,y) that will handle the position/increment on x and y respectively. See when you do this x = (0 * Math.cos t * 0.005) the circule just get moved from up to down. In order to get a shape behavior you need to control the vector (x and y positions) over the time and use remainder to wrap up x and y position (%).

Regards.